# String replacement not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex, foreach, output, ini

My problem is:

I have an .ini file that I'm reading as follows:

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtb_path.Text, Encoding.Default);

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    // schreibt Zeile für Zeile auf den StringBuilder bis das Ende der Datei erreicht ist
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        content.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());

    // StringBuilder als String an die TextBox übergeben
    this.textBox1.Text = content.ToString();
```

Then I apply the following regex:

```
    string regex = @"^FensterGemerkt.+?\d+\.\d+\.\d+\,\ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\ :\ -{1}?\d+\,.*?$"; //@"^Fenster.*$";

    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

    // search in
    string input = content.ToString();
    //txtb_count.Text = "anzahl zeilen: " + Convert.ToString(content.Capacity);

    // run regex
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, regex, options);              

    // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(matches.Count));
    txtb_count.Text = Convert.ToString(matches.Count);
    string cleanup ="";          

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        // clean the ini
        cleanup = Regex.Replace(input, match.Value, "");

        // Output all matches                    
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "\n" + match.Value;
    }
```

The .ini file looks like this:

```
1
FensterGemerkt=12.11.2012, 10:42:37 : -32000,32744--31840,32768
Fenster=-32000,32744,160,24

2
FensterGemerkt=12.11.2012, 10:49:46 : 0,44-1024,768
Fenster=0,44,1024,724
```

What I want is that if regex matches the first entry:

```
FensterGemerkt=12.11.2012, 10:42:37 : -32000,32744--31840,32768
```

... then replace or remove it.

My app works, but only for the last entry in the .ini file.
I think I have a problem in my `foreach`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do this but the simplest answer to your problem is because you are resetting `cleanup` to always be the replacement of the last value.

try

```
    string cleanup =input;          

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        // clean the ini
        cleanup = Regex.Replace(cleanup, match.Value, "");

        // Output all matches                    
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "\n" + match.Value;
    }
```

A better solution would be, using Linq:

```
  Regex regex=new Regex(@"^FensterGemerkt.+?\d+\.\d+\.\d+\,\ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\ :\ -{1}?\d+\,.*?$"; //@"^Fenster.*$",RegexOptions.MultiLine);
  string cleanup=regex.Replace(input,string.Empty);
  string[] matches=regex.Matches(input).OfType<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value).ToArray();
  txtb_count.Text = Convert.ToString(matches.Length);
  textBox2.Text = string.Join('\n',matches);
```

Comment: thank you for this solution with the foreach,
i try to get my app riunning and then i try the the solution with linq, why i use this is better performance ?

Comment: @FrankFischer The for each solution is re-evaluating the entire input string to do a replace on every iteration of the for each where the `cleanup = regex.Replace(input,string.Empty)` is far more efficient.  The Linq line is likely to be more efficient (haven't measured it) because you are not repeatedly concatenating (`+=`) a string and you only update the Text property once.